# How to derive this equation (it has cross products)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors

I have an equation (Eq 10) given in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13375)
$$
\mathbf{\sigma}=
\frac{1}{V}\sum_{n,\vec k} \mathbf{J_{n,\vec k}^s}\times \mathbf{J_{n,\vec k}} \bigg(-\frac{\partial f_{n,\vec k}}{\partial \epsilon}\bigg)
\tag{10}
$$
here $J^s$ is spin current, $J$ is electron current and $f_{n\vec k}$ is Fermi distribution function. The electron current is defined as $\mathbf{J}=-e\mathbf{v}$. The $n$ is band index and $\epsilon$ is energy.

By using that at $T=0$, we have $(-\frac{\partial f_{n,\vec k}}{\partial \epsilon})=\delta(\epsilon_{n\vec k}-\epsilon_{F})$, they convert summation over $\vec k$ to an integral
$$
\mathbf{\sigma}=
\frac{e}{\hbar(2\pi)^3}\sum_{n}\oint_{\epsilon_n=\epsilon_F} \mathbf{\hat v_{n,\vec k}}\times \mathbf{J_{n,\vec k}^s} dS
\tag{11}
$$
where $\mathbf{\hat v_{n,\vec k}}=\mathbf{v_{n,\vec k}}/v_{n,\vec k}$ is local normal of the Fermi surface unit vector.

And then they apply some identity and get
$$
\mathbf{\sigma}=
\frac{e}{\hbar(2\pi)^3}\sum_{n}\iiint_{\epsilon_n\leq\epsilon_F} \nabla_{\vec k} \times \mathbf{J_{n,\vec k}^s} dk^3
\tag{12}
$$
Can someone please help me how they get equation $(11)$ and $(12)$ from equation $(10)$?

---

**Edit (My progress so far):**

The tricky part is reaching $(11)$ from $(10)$. I started by using identity
$$
\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\vec k} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3\vec k
$$
together with $(-\frac{\partial f_{n,\vec k}}{\partial \epsilon})=\delta(\epsilon_{n\vec k}-\epsilon_{F})$, and $\mathbf{J}=-e\mathbf{v}=-\frac{e}{\hbar}\frac{\partial h(\vec k)}{\partial \vec k}$ in equation $(10)$

$$
\mathbf{\sigma}=
\frac{e}{\hbar (2\pi)^3}\sum_{n} \int d^3 \vec k \frac{\partial h(\vec k)}{\partial \vec k}  \times  \mathbf{J_{n,\vec k}^s} \delta(\epsilon_{n\vec k}-\epsilon_{F})
\tag{A}
$$
here $h(\vec k)$ is Hamiltonian given in $\vec k$-space.

It seems like I am going in the right direction, at least the factor other than integration is the same as Equation $(11)$. I don't know how to proceed from here. I am sure the term $\frac{\partial h(\vec k)}{\partial \vec k}$  is connected with energy $\epsilon_{n\vec k}$.

Comment: 11->12 is just Stoke's theorem right?

Comment: Do a search on "volume integral of a curl." That's what (12) is. That's the research you should have done.

Comment: @BillN yes I have done that. I thought the Strokes theorem only converts line integrals into the curl. I get the how to reach (12) from (11). Actually, the main difficulty for me is to reach (11) from (10). Any comments about that.

Comment: @jacob1729 yes, it is. I get the second step. Thanks